# how add a value to the list that in singleton class? (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

this is my code
[image]

how I can add some string  to my items list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `List<String>.filled(1, "")` constructor has a third parameter `growable` and defaults to false. so this line creates a fixed list by default and you cannot add new values to it, you should use this instead

```
List<String>.filled(1, "", growable: true);
```

this will make the list growable and now you can add new entries.